Ошибка в с++ отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "sort"
Хочу отсортировать вектор:
vector< pair<pair<unicodeString, unicodeString>, int> > pairsFreq;
sort(pairsFreq.begin(), pairsFreq.end(), comparePairs);

vs code ругается на сорт пишет:
"отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "sort", соответствующие списку аргументов"
компаратор перегружен как надо вроде:
bool comparePairs(
    const pair<pair<unicodeString, unicodeString>, int>& x,
    const pair<pair<unicodeString, unicodeString>, int>& y
) {
    if (x.second > y.second) {
        return true;
    } else if (x.second < y.second) {
        return false;
    }
    assert(x.second == y.second);
    unicodeString s1 = x.first.first + x.first.second;
    unicodeString s2 = y.first.first + y.first.second;
    return (s1 < s2);
}

Оператор сравнения строк тоже перегружен
В чем проблема, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Стесняюсь спросить... #include<algorithm> у вас прописан?... просто сам код вроде (при замене unicodeString на обычную, так как что там в ней, неизвестно) компилируется. Если все инклуды записаны, то смотрите в свой unicodeString...

Прочитайте про [mcve] и добавьте его в вопрос.
